# Nonlinear Sylvester-Like Equation

Tags: nonlinear-programming, nonlinear-equations

Maybe you can point me to some results already developed for this.

I have to solve for $X$ the following "Sylvester-like" equation:

$$ AX - XB = F(X)$$

where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{a\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times b}$, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $F(X)$ is a nonlinear function of the elements of X.

I know I can solve this using generic numerical algorithms to solve for the roots of $ AX - XB - F(X) = 0$. Nevertheless, I would like to know if there is any algorithm or procedure that actually exploits the "Sylvester-like" structure of the equation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please [don't cross post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648951/nonlinear-sylvester-like-equation). at the very least, you should include a link to the identical question you've posted on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Could perchance your equation be rewritten as a nonsymmetric algebraic Riccati equation $AX-XB = XCX+D$? There is a lot of theory on those.

Comment: Sorry, GoHokies, my mistake!

Comment: Federico Poloni, thanks for the comment. I've one particular case which can be written in that way. Any relevant link to recommend ?

Comment: @NicoF. You need to use the 'at' symbol if you want me to get notified. Basically, solutions can be computed through certain invariant subspaces, and there are several methods to get them. If you don't have special sign/symmetry properties, I suggest the Schur method in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042705003560. You may check also http://riccati.dm.unipi.it/nsare/index.html, and if you wish to see other methods also http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/050647669 and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00211-005-0673-7.